Using ua741 with an Arduino to increase the voltage range of a photodiode
I am trying to follow the instructions on this site to boost the voltage range output by a BPW34 using a ua741 opamp.
It isn't working. I believe my opamps are not broken as I have tested them according to this video using a multi-meter in diode mode. It reports a voltage drop exactly the same as the video.
Looking online and in the datasheets for the ua741c by ST Microsystems it says it works over a voltage range of 5-15 volts. Many comments online say it needs 10 volts to work properly.
Obviously in this example the Arduino is only supplying 5V. Is it reasonable to expect that it would work as described on the page "And for the photodiode + opAmp circuit, the output swings from 2V (darkness) up to 4.2V (intense light)"?
I have the 5V line hooked up to a 5V bench power supply then I have the output wired to my USB oscilliscope. I've included a photo of my circuit (the exact same as the one on the site) as well as two oscilliscope captures, one with the opamp installed, and one without the opamp installed. Both appear to be identical.
My specific questions are.

Is this circuit design OK? (The design circuit and the circuit he made in the breadboard appear functionally equivalent, I made the same one he made in the breadboard, my capacitor is 80nF instead of his 100nF, also I don't know what brand ua741 he is using, but otherwise it should be identical.)
Is it going to be operating within the normal specified working range of the opamp?
If the answer to both of the above is YES, then what might I be doing wrong?
If the answer is NO, and I need a different opamp (as I expect below based on the EDIT information), then what would be an appropriate opamp.

Design from website:

Physical circuit from website:

My breadboard with opamp:

My breadboard without opamp:

Oscilliscope capture with opamp (PWM flashlight goes low when light is on from flashlight):

Oscilliscope capture without opamp (PWM flashlight goes low when light is on from flashlight):

EDIT: The answer to this question seems to suggest that this example is not within specifications of the ua741 opamp.

Now look about halfway down and find "input voltage range", which will show a minimum of +/- 12. What this means is that, if your input voltage is less than 3 volts from either supply (for +/- 15), the IC is simply not guaranteed to work.

It seems like perhaps a different opamp is necessary. Can anyone recommend a different opamp? I am looking. I am using this with an Arduino just like the original example. I need a small SMD form factor opamp. I will need two of them for two different photodiodes, so a dual opamp package is fine. I don't need it to be be rail-to-rail but I need it to be cheap, and possible to use with a simple circuit like this one with only a resistor and capacitor for each opamp.
EDIT2: Increasing the Vcc of the opamp to 15 V makes it boost the output from 0.3 V to 3 V. So I definitely need a different opamp that will work with a 5 V Vcc supply.
EDIT3: This table has some good recommendations for opamps to be used with Arduinos (5V Vcc.) I also need to take into consideration the slew it seems, as I will need the opamp to have a slew no lower than 0.5V/uS which rules out the MCP6042, that page otherwise recommends in favour of the MPC6022.

Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp

I'm relatively confident at this point that the issue is that the behavior of ua741 is not properly defined when one is within 3V of Vcc+ or Vcc-. Since operating between 0 and 5V means one is continuously in this range, it is not guaranteed to function as explained in the example on the ua741. This is discussed in this response.
A suitable op-amp for my purposes seems like it would be either the MCP6022 or MCP6002 depending on the slew rate required.  A good comparison of various opamps that are compatible with the arduino 5V Vcc+ is discussed on this page.

Seems that a low supply voltage going to pin 6 renders that 741 inoperable. Circuit looks good: a rail-to-rail opamp spec'd for +5V supply should work. Oscilloscope output of -0.4V indicates that BPW34 photocurrents pass through 10k resistor to oscilloscope input...the photodiode seems OK.

@glen_geek, thanks for your comment. I am curious what would be the cause of the low supply voltage on pin 6? pin 6 is connected to the oscilliscope, it's also connected through the 10k ohm resistor to the pin 2 which is the inverting input. The photodiode does indeed work. I am still curious if this should be able to work, despite what I referenced in the other stackexchange answer, what is going wrong. I disassembled my breadboard already so it will take time to rebuild it re-test any potential modifications at this point though.

Sorry Peter, my error...DC supply pin to 741 op amp is #7, not #6. Opamp manufacturer says nothing about its operation at such low DC supply as +5V: it seems that 741 output pin neither supplies current nor sinks current (it is open-circuit) according to your measurements. Your MCP6022 suggestion should work OK, except at very low light levels where Vout falls between 0V and +20mV. You should choose a much smaller capacitor than 100nf if speed is important. Also add a capacitor across the DC supply with short path to the chip.

@glen_geek, thanks so much great tips that will help me with my project. I ordered my PCB with the MCP6022 hopefully it will work well :)

@glen_geek thank again for the tip about using a smaller value than 100nF MCP2022 worked perfectly for my application. I needed at 47 pF capacitor and a 500 kOhm resistor to get good results. Also I had to switch the orientation of my photodiodes because they were backwards at first (hard to know which way around to put them when your using it as an inverting amplifier).
